# Insert and load script file in HTML after page is 100% completly loaded

Tags: javascript, html, performance, ads

**This problem is not a simple problem of just creating and injecting the script file.**

I want to optimize my website which loads script files of google ads.

**Problem**: When script files of google ads load parallelly with HTML files then page load speed drastically decreased.

**Solution I came up with**: I decided to load the script files of google ads after the webpage is 100% completely loaded (or even 100-200miliseconds after page 100% loaded)

**Solutions I tried are as follows with details:**

1. Created a function to load script file and used `window.onload = loadGoogleSyndication()`. But it actually loads the script before the complete loading of the HTML document. (i can observe it in the speed test of the site)

   ```js
    function loadGoogleSyndication() {
      const googleSyndication = document.createElement('script');
      googleSyndication.type = 'text/javascript';
      googleSyndication.async = true;
      googleSyndication.src = 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js';
      const script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      script.parentNode.insertBefore(googleSyndication, script);
    }
    window.onload = loadGoogleSyndication()
   ```
2. Secondly I used `document.onload = loadGoogleSyndication()`. But again it loads file before complete loading of page.

```js
    window.onload = loadGoogleSyndication()
```

3. Same problem is with `window.addEventlister("load", loadGoogleSyndication())`

**Only solution that worked**:
I use `setTimeout` property and loaded the file after 2.5 sec and then it worked. (2.5 sec can be 2sec also for fast internet connection)

**This works**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    loadGoogleSyndication();
  }, 2500);
}, true);
```

But is there any solution other than this where the script loads exactly after(or after 100 milliseconds) 100% HTML file loaded? Because using `setTimeout` property is throwing a knife in darkness we exactly don't know when the file HTML file load is completed.

**One other solution could be to load file after window scrolled `window.onscroll`, but I don't want to use it.**

Answer (score 1):

Try `DOMContentLoaded` which fires only when all the nodes in the page have been constructed in the DOM tree.

```js
function loadGoogleSyndication() {
  const googleSyndication = document.createElement('script');
  googleSyndication.type = 'text/javascript';
  googleSyndication.async = true;
  googleSyndication.src = 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js';
  const script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  script.parentNode.insertBefore(googleSyndication, script);
}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadGoogleSyndication)
```

Comment: Sorry @brk, technically the event `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered even before the `load` event. So this did not work.

Comment: @SatishChandraGupta DOMContentLoaded_event triggers only when dom is 
 completely ready https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: is checked out the link and confused between which event is triggered first, but solution is not working here.